How to split connection and query execution into two methods System.Data.SQLite;
What is the best way to split connection and executing query into two methods?
using System.Data.SQLite;
internal SQLiteConnection ConnectToDb()
{
    using (SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("@"DB\SWDB.db;"))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
    }
    return dbConnection;
}

internal Qruery()
{
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, dbConnection))
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ......

    }
    dbConnection.Close();
}

Since both objects are disposable, dbConnection is destroyed after using is done, so query cannot be made.

Is it C#? Please use the appropriate language tag.

You should not have a ConnectToDb method because this does more harm than good. What is it's benefit? You could have a CreateDbConnection method, but don't open it there.

didnt get your point. just a name?! i wanted to do some stuff after i create a connection object and later make a query. for now i removed using from the connection, and used try catch. didnt find a better solution

A using block causes the Dispose() method to be called on the object when the block ends. Note the object is not "destroyed", it still exists, which is why you can return it from your function. If you want to return it and use it, don't use the using statement. However you absolutely must call Dispose on it once you've finished with it, otherwise you'll quickly run out of available connections and wonder why your application mysteriously gets stuck waiting for a previous connection to time out.

But as @TimSchmelter says, this idiom will do more harm than good. Create a connection exactly where it's needed and dispose it immediately. If you want to "do some stuff" create a connection for just that. Don't worry that creating a connection is slow, it's not - once you dispose it, it goes into the connection pool and your next creation of a connection gets one out of the pool.
